# R `slide()` function doesn't return lag/lead values for character variables?

Tags: r

I'm checking for duplicate Member ID numbers in a healthcare dataset and am having trouble creating lead and lag Member ID variables with the `slide` function.

```
library(DataCombine)
data <- data.frame(MEMBNO=c('A001','B002','B002','C003'), x=c(10,200,300,500))
data
  MEMBNO   x
1   A001  10
2   B002 200
3   B002 300
4   C003 500

data <- slide(data, Var = "MEMBNO", slideBy = -1)
data <- slide(data, Var = "MEMBNO", slideBy = 1)
data
   MEMBNO   x MEMBNO-1 MEMBNO1
1   A001  10       NA       2
2   B002 200        1       2
3   B002 300        2       3
4   C003 500        2      NA
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the new lead and lag variables, MEMBNO-1 and MEMBNO1, have been converted into numerical type instead of retaining the original Member ID character values.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The problem is likely your MEMBNO column is a factor rather than a character value. Try it with `data.frame(MEMBNO=c('A001','B002','B002','C003'), x=c(10,200,300,500), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: And not sure if `DataCombine` is a requirement for you but the more common `dplyr` package has `lead()` and `lag()` functions available that would have worked right away.

Comment: @MrFlick That worked, thanks so much!